# display image on another window when click select button using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello there I'm new to the world of Javascript, and I really really need help for school project.
What I want to do, is to display on another windows not only the text with the price, but also the image itself. I tried to add the id on the image and added it to function. Anybody please?
I have this code here in the body element along with other images:

Nike 1
            price:$110.99
 
           Size: 9  
           10  
           11

```
       <input type= submit value=submit onclick="a()">
```

This is my script function:

```
       <script>
       function a(){
       var size ="";
       var price = 0;
       if(document.getElementById('nike1').checked)
       {
       price=document.getElementById("nike1").value;
       var x =document.getElementById("myimg").src;
       }

       else if(document.getElementById('nike2').checked)
       {
       price=document.getElementById('nike2').value;
       }

       var inputs = document.getElementsByName('r1');
       for(var i =0; i<inputs.lenght; i++){
       if(inputs[i].checked){
       size = inputs[i].value;
       }
       }


       var inputs1 = document.getElementsByName('r2');
       for(var i =0; i <inputs1.lenghts;i++){
       if(inputs1[i].checked){
       size=inputs1[i].value;
       }
       }

       var myWindow = window.open("","MsgWindow","width=200,height=400");
       myWindow.document.write("<p><h1>Order Detail</h1> Your ordered Nike shoes<br/>                                                                                        Size:"+size + "<br/>Price:S"+ price + "</p>");
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please indent you code for readability. Here it is, a little bit cleaned and with error fixes.

```
   function a() {
       var size, price;
       if (document.getElementById('nike1').checked) {
           price = document.getElementById("nike1").value;
           var x = document.getElementById("myimg").src;
       } else if (document.getElementById('nike2').checked) {
           price = document.getElementById('nike2').value;
       }

       var inputs = document.getElementsByName('r1');
       for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
           if (inputs[i].checked) {
               size = inputs[i].value;
           }
       }


       var inputs1 = document.getElementsByName('r2');
       for (var i = 0; i < inputs1.length; i++) {
           if (inputs1[i].checked) {
               size = inputs1[i].value;
           }
       }

       var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200,height=400");
       myWindow.document.write('<p><h1>Order Detail</h1> Your ordered Nike shoes<br/>'+
       '<img src="path/to/your/image.png" alt="Nike shoes"></img>'+
       '<p>Size: ' + size + '<br/>Price: ' + price + '</p>');
   }
```

To solve your problem, write an img element with a src attribute. Change "path/to/your/image.png" with the real path to the image you want to display.

There were also errors in your code. Your two for loops contained a wrong value: your wrote lenght in the first and lenghts in the second. I fixed it. I tested it and it works. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qFq5/) is fairly simple and incomplete but shows you the result.

Comment: hello Filsmick, thanks for your reply and your advice. Next try i'll try better with indentation. I tried to follow your example and the image it's not showing. Do I need to add another array? Please Help me, i wish i could upload the all code here.

Comment: You CAN upload all the code. There is something awesome called jsFiddle that is overused here. You can create a demo of what you code does so we can fix it. http://jsfiddle.net/

But perhaps I can help you without it. Edit your first post and add your new code, with your try of my solution.

Comment: i still can't get it. I'm able to display the shoe on the first but not the rest. Hey Filsmick would it be ok if i can send it to u?

Comment: Don't worry if you can't display it. Paste your code in jsFiddle in the appropriated boxes, hit save and send me the link you get in your URL bar. That's all!

Comment: hey Filsmick thanks for your help, i finally figured it out. Now i'm actually i'm trying to add a select input inside the mywindow.document. Basically, what i really want is that when the window is displayed, to include a select button to link to another page html.

Comment: It wasn't the main question. I suggest you to learn JavaScript in deep  instead of asking us everything you want to do, because if you continue thus, you will find yourself knowing nothing about how things work. I suggest you [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) or JavaScript: the definitive guide. They are excellent.
If I helped you to solve your initial problem, displaying an image in a window using document.write, please mark my answer as the answer to your question.

Comment: sure i do that. Thanks.